# Instantiating objects(Entry point)

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and Xcode. I have got two swift files which contain's two classes A and B. I need to instantiate an object of Class A to start the program.How would I do that in swift?. I am familiar with Java and I am aware of the main program where the execution starts. How would I do the same in swift? I am not trying to create an iOS or Xcode App.

I have played around with playgrounds and everything works if you put it in a single file. I have created a package and added the swift files. The build is successful but there is no output. The code below is the Source code that I would use in a playground to start the program. How would I do it in an xcode project?

```
    var b = Shop()
    b.IssueOrder(quantity: 100, code: "R12")
    b.IssueOrder(quantity: 156, code: "L09")
    b.IssueOrder(quantity: 13, code: "T58")
```

I was wondering if there are any swift veterans could help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Look at this structure.

[image]

I have created `User.swift` file in source folder in playground and make use of it in playground.

Class in Source folder : `User.swift`

```
import Foundation

public class User {

    var firstName : String?
    var lastName : String?

    public init(_ firstName : String?, _ lastName : String?) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    public func getFullName() -> String?{
        return (firstName ?? "" ) + (lastName ?? "")
    }
}
```

Use it in playground :

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
var user = User("Sagar", "Gondaliya")
print("My FullName : \(user.getFullName()!)")
```

Output:  `My FullName : Sagar Gondaliya`

Just make sure that class and its method which you want to access should be marked as `public`.

Comment: This would be correct if you are building an iOS app which I am not.

Comment: I have three swift files in a test package and I want to run a swift file to start execution just like we do in java public static void main program. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yeah kind of. Is there a way I can make it work ?. If I put everything in a playground and instantiate the code I posted above. Everything works. I was trying to make it .swift files

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath : May be you are looking like this one.

Comment: Hey . Just One more questions. The method you suggested works. But how would you debug the program if you create a playground project instead of the normal one?

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath: There is no support for Debugging in playground as of now : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186805/swift-playground-with-debugger-support

Comment: So we are back to square one. So there appears to be no way in swift to build programs that have debugging support unless you are building iOS, MacOS applications?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159323/discussion-between-technerd-and-varun-babu-pozhath).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this can easily be done using Swift package manager via command line. There are very little resources out there so I thought I will go ahead and write the answer myself.

1. Create a new Directory and cd into it.
2. Create a new package using the following command. This will create the project structure for you. **It has a main.swift file which will serve as the entry point for the application**

   `swift package init --type executable`
3. Build the project

   `swift build`
4. Execute the project by running the below command where Project is the name of the directory you created(becomes the name of the project)

   `.build/debug/Project`
5. You will see the output of the source code in the main.swift file in the terminal